# Products of e to fractional exponents

Tags: exponentiation

I'm quite happy dealing with simple exponents, or so I thought. I've come across the following product and solution:

$$  e^{-x^2/2\alpha^2}\times e^{-2x^2/\alpha^2}=e^{-5x^2/2\alpha^2} $$

When I work this through, I get the following instead:

$$ e^{\frac{-x^2-2x^2}{2\alpha^2+\alpha^2}} \rightarrow e^{-3x^2/3\alpha^2} $$

I presumed I would just use addition on the exponents as they are the same base. But the 2 coefficient threw me. Should I look to simplify them first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made a mistake when adding the fractions: the exponent should be
$$-\frac{x^2}{2\alpha^2}-\frac{2x^2}{\alpha^2}=-\frac{x^2}{2\alpha^2}-\frac{4x^2}{2\alpha^2}=-\frac{5x^2}{2\alpha^2}$$

Comment: Ah, so I just needed to make the denominators the same by multiplying top and bottom by 2? on the rhs?

Comment: That's right, yes

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thanks for prompt reply.

Answer (score 0):

Since $-\frac{x^2}{2 \alpha ^2} -\frac{2 x^2}{\alpha ^2} = -\frac{5 x^2}{2 \alpha ^2} \neq \frac{-3 x^2}{3 \alpha ^2} = \frac{-x^2 - 2 x^2}{2 \alpha ^2 + \alpha ^2} $, the first formula is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the addition of the demoninator. You are right that $$e^{-x^2/2a^2}\cdot e^{-2x^2/a^2}=e^{-x^2/2a^2-4x^2/a^2}=e^{-5x^2/a^2}$$